# How to run a pkg file in the Mac OS X installer package?

Tags: macos, installation, package

Here is the situation, I have my app ready to be packaged. But my app needs an USB driver to insure it can recognize required device. I am hoping to make a package file contains USB driver + my app. I already have the Mac version of USB driver, it's another package file. So I  need when user run my package, it will automatically run the USB driver installer, then copy my app to specific folder to finish the whole installation.

Any app recommandation to finish this job? In windows, there is ShieldInstaller, anything similar to this? Thanks!